# Visual Studio Add In template not showing on Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ssms, add-in

I'm trying to create an add-in for Sql Server Management Studio following the steps in [this tutorial](https://sqljudo.wordpress.com/31-days-of-sql-server-management-studio/ssms-day-27-building-a-custom-add-in-extension/). However, my problem is that there is no Visual Studio Add in project template under Other project types > Extensibility.
This is what the node in my Visual Studio contains:

[image: Visual Studio Screenshot]

But, according to the tutorial there should be a Visual Studio Add in project in this node. Can this be because VS15 does not support this type of add in, or should I install something?

Comment: What version of SSMS you want to target?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio 2015 doesn't have an add-in template and doesn't run add-ins any more - only extensions. Though you can probably continue to work on an add-in project created in an older version of Visual Studio.

SSMS 2016 also doesn't support add-ins any more - only MEF components and selected extensions.

Comment: I am targeting all SSMS versions from 2008 and up. So, there is no way to create a extension / plugin / add-in for SSMS 2016? Because I really need to provide some external functionality for SSMS with an extension that can be accessed from the 'Tools' menu.

Comment: SSMS 2016 currently uses a whitelist for extensions. The SSMS team plans to remove this restriction, but for now you need to contact them to get a "white" extension id. As an alternative for SSMS 2016, maybe you can write your plugin using my Visual Commander extension.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have to install [Visual Studio SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166441.aspx). With this SDK you can extend Visual Studio features. And since SSMS is built on top of VS you will be able to create SSMS plugins as well.